# Access the JSON response from webview of android

Tags: java, android, json, webview

On Android, I have a `webView`. I'm loading a `url` on it. Firstly, I get a login page of `Facebook` and after filling login details it gives me a `JSON Response` on same `webView`.

I'm using this code to load that `URL` but now I don't know how to get that `JSON Response` in a `string` what I got on finished of that `url`.

```
WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        wb.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
    }
};
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wb.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
wb.loadUrl("http://pqrs.abcde.com/facebook");
```

The format of `JSON Response` is:

```
{"status":"success","msg":"You have successfully logged in."}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Build a class called MyJavaScriptInterface. And MyJavaScriptInterface to WebView.

```
    WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            wb.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    };
    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
    wb.loadUrl("http://pqrs.abcde.com/facebook");
    wb.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
```

---

```
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;
    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;      
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
        System.out.println(html);
    }

}
```

---

Note: From you are required to remove window in wb.loadUrl("javascript:...");.
And @JavascriptInterface before "public void showHTML".

You can get content from showHtml(..) in html parameter.

Comment: What are doing with the context that you pass to the constructor? You are naming a class "JavaScriptInterface", you can change that Interface.

Comment: JSON response is not coming brother

Answer (score 0):

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(webdata);
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```