# How to get the JSON response from WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I have an app using WebView. When user open the WebView, it will direct to a Login Page and user will input the username and password to Login. After user press Login button, the server will response to WebView that login success or fail. So how can I get that response and handle it in Android App ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268764/2196176).

Comment: you can use addJavascriptInterface to your webview like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075048/3333848

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847619/access-the-json-response-from-webview-of-android check it

Comment: I have tried with solutions above but it can not work. My web page using Javascript and when user Login I want to get JSON response and handle it, someone have an idea for me ? I just a beginner.

Comment: The link of @ManthanPatel seem not help me, because I can not intercede to Javascript file